# Relations between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have a mutiple choice question on finding the relation but I seem to be blanking. Can someone explain to me how this works?

> Let $X = \{2,3,4\}$ and $Y = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. If a relation $P$ between $X$ and $Y$ is defined by:
>                                    $$xPy\text{ if }x < 2y$$
>   then which of the ordered pairs listed below belong to $P$?

The answers available are

> A       (2,0)
>
> B   (2,1)
>
> C   (2,2)
>
> D   (2,3)
>
> E   (2,4)
>
> F   (3,0)
>
> G   (3,1)
>
> H   (3,2)
>
> I   (3,3)
>
> J   (3,4)
>
> K   (4,0)
>
> L   (4,1)
>
> M   (4,2)
>
> N   (4,3)
>
> O   (4,4)
>
> P   none of them

Thanks, it's appreciated.

Comment: It is a very very straightforward application of the definition of relation, so it is not very useful if we do it for you. It will help you more if you explain what you didn't understand in the definition of relation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The relation contains the ordered pair $(3,4)$, since $3 < 2(4)$. The relation doesn't contain the ordered pair $(4,1)$, since $4 \geq 2(1)$. Hopefully you get the idea and can test the other ordered pairs yourself.